# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in

Tags: php, poo

espero que me pueda ayudar.
Tengo mi conexión en poo y estoy intentando listar datos con while
todo hasta ahi bien pero al llegar  a la linea de :

```
while($datos=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
```

Me sale esto:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\Conexion\conexion.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\Conexion\conexion.php on line 33

```
class Conexion{
 //Propiedades o  atributos

 private $host;
 private $user;
 private $pass;
 private $db;

public function conectar(){
$this->host='127.0.0.1';
$this->user='root';
$this->pass='';
$this->dataname='crud';

$con = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
return $con;
}

}


$conexion= new Conexion();
$con=$conexion->conectar();

$sql='select * from personas';
$resultado = $con->query($sql);



while($datos=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
echo $datos;
}
```

Comment: Describe mejor el problema que tienes, ya que dices *me sale este error* pero no dices cual es

Comment: Osea dice que tengo un error al  almacenar  los  datos en  fetch_assoc  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\Conexion\conexion.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\Conexion\conexion.php on line 33

Comment: Tu error es muy simple, en tus propiedades tienes esto: `$this->db;` y luego lo invocas asi `$this->dataname`, usa el mismo nombre con el que declaraste la propiedad

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error parte de que a través de la *pseudovariable* `$this` intentas acceder a una propiedad que no esta definida dentro de tu clase.

Entonces si declaras a `$db` es a esta misma la que debes invocar cuando en el método la usas para asignarle un valor y posterior como ya lo tienes es esta la que debes usar dentro de la instancia de la clase *mysqli*

Te expongo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

class Conexion
{
    public string $db = 'una cadena';
    
    public function conectar(): string
    {
        return $this->db1;
    }
}

var_dump((new Conexion)->db);
var_dump((new Conexion)->conectar());
```

Obtendré esto como salida:

> string(10) "una cadena" 
> Notice: Undefined property: Conexion::$db1 in [...][...] on line 11

Cuando accedo a una propiedad que si existe obtengo el valor, sin embargo cuando invoco al método obtengo el mensaje de error por que este mismo a su vez invoca a una propiedad no definida.